# How do I make my PHP AJAX code return false into my false jQuery block?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some jQuery that looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(json)
                {           
                    // ? :)



                }
                error : function() 
                {
                    alert("ajax error");
                }
            });
```

when I am writing my AJAX code, in case of some validation or database errors, I want to stop execution and return to the jQuery error block.  What do I have to do in the PHP AJAX code in order to return things to the error block instead of the success block?

Thanks!!

Comment: Something like this I'd imagine : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd have to use the success function and capture what is returned for example:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/problems/vote.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(json)
            {           
                if(json == "error"){
                   alert("error");
                }



            }
        });
```

you'll only use `error:` if there is a problem with the AJAX request

Comment: If the php script encounters a fatal error, `if (json == "error")` won't work. Instead you can write a javascript code that will execute if you do not receive an expected value of 'json', like `if (json != "success")`